# Failing curling the data

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get the data by submitting this form [here](http://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BR12AWRentalEnquiry/BR12PSearch.faces)

click "town" a form will appear.

Although i can get the data, but it is a 500 error pages, i have struggled 5 hours and my codes

```
$url = 'http://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BR12AWRentalEnquiry/BR12PSearch.faces';
$fields['searchByTown:frmSearchByTown']='searchByTown:frmSearchByTown';
$fields['searchByTown:frmSearchByTown:selTown']='AMK';
$fields['searchByTown:frmSearchByTown:txtBlkFrm']=1;
$fields['searchByTown:frmSearchByTown:txtBlkTo']=10;
$fields['searchByTown:frmSearchByTown:dteStart1']="Jul 2013";
$fields['searchByTown:frmSearchByTown:dteEnd1']="Oct 2013";
$fields['avax.faces.ViewState']='j_id1:j_id3';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,$fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Don't use `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false`; instead, use an updated CA bundle to verify the remote certificate. That said, you're not even connecting via SSL at all.

Comment: hi, can you elaborate more about this? actually in my link, i did not see they using https, so i guess ssl is turned off

Comment: The above code returns a 200 status code; I don't see the error. Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi the form is not submitting, the result redisplay the form

Comment: That's a different problem altogether. The form is probably XSRF protected, so you have to GET the page first and then POST the form.

Comment: Hi, the strange thing is if i manually copy the form to my localhost, then post to "http://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/BR12AWRentalEnquiry/BR12PSearch.faces", it display the result correctly. However when i do using curl, simply fail.

Comment: In that case you missed to send something across; but SO is not the right place for that imho.